# Is there something you have to change if you have a lot of elif's?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to make a unit converter, so I'll need to put in a lot of conversions. For the fifth elif in the list, it says it is a syntax error.

I've tried changing it to an if but then it says my variable cent_mi isn't defined. Any ideas?

```
else:
    convert_answer = raw_input("What would you like to convert? (_____ to ______)? ")
    if convert_answer == 'centimeter to feet' or convert_answer == 'cent to feet':
        cent_f = raw_input("How many centimeters? ")
        print str(int(cent_f) / float(30.48)) + " feet."
    elif convert_answer == 'centimeter to inch' or convert_answer == 'cent to inch':
        cent_i = raw_input("How many centimeters? ")
        print str(int(cent_i) / float(2.54)) + " inches."
    elif convert_answer == 'centimeter to yard' or convert_answer == 'cent to yard':
        cent_y = raw_input("How many centimeters? ")
        print  str(int(cent_y) / float(91.44)) + " yards."
    elif convert_answer == 'centimeter to meter' or convert_answer == 'cent to meter':
        cent_m = raw_input("How many centimeters? ")
        print  str(int(cent_m) / 100) + " meters."
    elif convert_answer ==  'cent to kilometer' or convert_answer == 'centimeter to kilometer':
        feet_km = raw_input("How many centimeters? ")
        print str(int(feet_km) / 100000 + " kilometers."
    elif convert_answer == 'cent to mile' or convert_answer == 'centimeter to mile':
    # This is the elif that raises an error.
        cent_mi = raw_input("How many centimeters? ")
        print str(int(cent_mi) / float(160934.4)) + " miles."
    elif convert_answer ==  'feet to cent' or convert_answer == 'feet to centimeter':
        feet_c = raw_input("How many feet? ")
        print str(int(feet_c) * float(30.48)) + " centimeters."
```

I thought you could have as many elif's as you wanted, but the fifth elif raises an syntax error.

Comment: It's not the `elif`s. It's the line below your comment (`==` instead of `=`).

Comment: You put `cent_mi == raw_input("How many centimeters? ")` it should be `cent_mi = raw_input("How many centimeters? ")`

Comment: I might be doing something else wrong, but it still doesn't fix my code when I change == to =.

Comment: Seems like a perfect candidate for the use of switch & case. Unfortunately, google leads me to believe python not to have 'em *boo*! This page seems to have a reasonable discussion on the topic (seems - I haven't read much of it!) https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesn't this line need some more closing brackets

```
 print str(int(feet_km) / 100000 + " kilometers."
```

something like

```
print str(int(feet_km) / 100000) + " kilometers."
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed my problem! Kind of a careless error on my part.

Comment: Sorry, I can't vote up, I don't have enough reputation. I accepted your answer though!